I cant get my rp 4 with kali installation to connect to my wifi (headless)
i did a headless kali installation on a pi 4 model B 8GB using pi imager, and since kali doesnt support pi imager's custom os settings (eg. ssh, pre configuring wireless networks), i looked up on the internet on how to do a headless install on kali, and they said i need to make an empty ssh file and a wpa_supplicant.conf file for it to work.
no matter how much i try, i just cant get it to connect. for the moment, the wpa file looks like this
network={
        ssid="swampgooch"
        #psk="3141592653"
        psk=17c3b372bafe8476c084e2297bbe7641daea24b02a54e3a7e5e5be0caf275513
    }

i just cant get it to work. i tried doing a normal raspbian os installation, used the inbuilt imager os customization, and it works flawlessly.
is there something im missing here that i should know? gosh i wish kali supported os customization.

Welcome.  Please consider the points made in the section here titled Is Kali Linux Right For You?.  For example, "it is NOT a recommended distribution if you’re unfamiliar with Linux" -> Your problem would not be hard to deal with if you were familiar with linux and had some networking experience.  If you are not knowledgeable in those areas, the solution is probably to use a distribution that is not going to make life as difficult for you.

@goldilocks i am familiar with linux, i need to get this on for a group project, and it just doesnt work, so id appreciate any help and not some repeated message about why i should use another distro. i just need the right help to fix this. thank you.

Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me? - If you need to ask, then Kali Linux is not the right distribution for you.

"i am familiar with linux" -> Then surely you are able to put the SD card in another machine and configure the wifi that way?!!!??  This is pretty simple stuff, which is also why I would not expect anyone to bother regurgitating a solution that is already regurgitated enough online (but feel free to wait...). "not some repeated message about..." -> To be fair, from the perspective of other people, this is yet-another-repeated-message about how I want to use Kali but I do not understand network configuration basics.

@goldilocks i did just that, i used another linux machine to make this wpa file, and putting this in a raspbian os boot partition works but not in this case, no matter how much i try. even in the documentation it says to do the same thing and it should work this way, so idk what yall be so hot about lol. and i couldnt find the same problem anywhere else, im sorry if this bothered you lol.

I did not mean put the wpa file on the boot partition.  I meant configure networking on the root fs as you would any other linux system (edit /etc/wpa_suppicant/..., enable that and a dhcp client service, etc).  AFAIK, Kali does not include a mechanism to auto-configure using files from the boot partition, ie., you cannot do a purely headless install starting with a stock image.  Either you attach a screen and keyboard and set up networking and ssh that way, or you make the appropriate changes to the card using another system. If you cannot do either of those things, you are out of luck.

So check this link out, the short answer is, I used
ifconfig wlan0 up after installing Kali for my Pi-4, and Wifi on Kali works now.
I searched all over as well, and thinking it could NOT have been this simple while people are arguing in forums about driver issues, but maybe something changed while I was giving up on it and this happened to pop up in my searching after reading this thread.
I dont care how many people ask, I will share the links, I will help people and hope they are not selfish with the information gained. The only problem in Linux is when people require this mentality because someone refused to help them and now they are some self made guru.
Unix Stack Exchange
clean link:
unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287789/can-detect-but-not-connect-to-wifi-network-kali-raspberry-pi

thank you so much. i really appreciate your help a lot.
